# Problemas al calcular la media ponderada y agrupar por categorías en R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-dplyr

Estoy intentando armar una tabla que me calcule la media ponderada de las variaciones de precios de distintos productos según su categoría. El data frame desde el que parto tiene esta forma:

[image: df = datos_variaciones_b]

Y mi codigo es:

```
variaciones_por_categoria <- datos_variaciones_b %>% group_by(Nombre,Nomenclatura) %>% summarise(Variacion= weighted.mean(datos_variaciones_b[2], w = datos_variaciones_b[7], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Esto me devuelve un df con la forma que quiero, pero le asigna la misma media ponderada a todas las categorías, cuando deberían ser distintas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy viendo donde está el error, probé cambiar puntos por comas en un intento de algo, pero no me queda claro. Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
summarise(Variacion = weighted.mean(datos_variaciones_b[2], 
                                    w = datos_variaciones_b[7], 
                                    na.rm = TRUE))
```

Particularmente con `datos_variaciones_b[2]` y `datos_variaciones_b[7]` les estas diciendo a `dplyr` que tome todas las filas del `data.frame` de las columnas indicadas y no las que corresponden a cada grupo, de ahí que el valor que obtienes sea siempre el mismo. Para indicar las filas únicamente de cada grupo, debes usar directamente el nombre de las variables, supongamos que se llamen `Col2` y `Col7`, deberías hacer algo así:

```
summarise(Variacion = weighted.mean(Col2, 
                                    w = Col7, 
                                    na.rm = TRUE))
```